# How can I make this custom design menu work in wordpress?

Tags: menus

I can make wordpress custom menu,but I got a problem with this type of menu. Can anybody give me any suggestion how to make this menu dynamic?

screenshot:
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ab3d6an94

HTML markup

```
                    <ul id="nav">
                        <li><a href="">World News <span>From Around The Globe</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Celebrity News <span>Juicy Hollywood Gossip</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Home Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Blog Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Full width Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Archive Page</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">Technology <span>Apps, Internet & Gadgets</span></a> </li>
                        <li><a href="">Lifestyle Tips <span>Your Health & Happiness</span></a> </li>

                     <ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your sub-labels below the main text in each item.

1. When building menu, set a custom name to menu item with  like this:

   World News From Around The Globe
2. Another method is to use a megamenu WordPress plugin, which supports two labels.

Comment: Thanks Alex! can you describe me more? how to set a custom name to menu item and whats the benefit of this? Actually I don't want to use plugins for menu.

Comment: I'm sorry, there is missed wrapping "<span>" in my previous answer.
The idea is to keep your HTML structure, so one of the simplest methods is to wrap needed words inside your menu items with <span>'s.

Go to your menu in "Appearance->Menus", and change the Navigation Label to something like on the screenshot:
http://note.io/VNQn98

Or tell me where you stacked exactly, clarify more please.

Comment: I already know what you suggested me above. But I just wanted to know a better idea to make that menu.But anyway Thanks Alex!

Comment: Ok, I think this article should help you then: http://www.wpexplorer.com/adding-custom-attributes-to-wordpress-menus/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is not the direct answer but as a bit of help, you can read this article that Chris Coyier kindly wrote few years ago on this painful topic http://digwp.com/2011/11/html-formatting-custom-menus/

But it looks like there is no easy ways for your idea :)
I guess you would want to use in these sub_labels page's meta titles? Have you tried to use "items_wrap" and "walker" parameters?
As good overal reference http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

But looks like you gonna need to ditch default wp_nav_menu function and build you own custome menu